# Remove widget and move up entire layout programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have an Activity contains some ImageView with button inside. If an event occout, i remove first button on top of the view like:

```
myImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

but in this way i have a blank space instead imageView, and i would that when this occour, entire layout move up (so the blank space doesn't appear). This is xml of firs two ImageView:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/facebook_opponent_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/button_facebook" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/numbers_opponent_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
    android:src="@drawable/button" />
```

FacebookOpponentButton is the one that should disappear. Maybe my problem is that other imageView has

```
android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
```

attribute?

Comment: Yes, marginTop creates the blank space. Maybe use marginBottom on the image that needs to disappear ?

Comment: What layout type are you using for?

Comment: I use RelativeLayout.
@2Dee also if i use marginBottom the situation will be the same: also if i remove first wiew, others have fixed distance from bottom of the screen

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the `marginTop` attribut here. Instead set your `numbers_opponent_button` **below** the `facebook_opponent_button` and remove the layout_alignParentTop attribute.

Proceed like this:

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/facebook_opponent_button"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:src="@drawable/button_facebook" />

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/numbers_opponent_button"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/facebook_opponent_button"
android:src="@drawable/button" />
```